# Xcode 7.3.1 error in all cocoa pod libraries that too suddenly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I just pushed code to bitbucket, shutdown pc and the next time I open the and build the project, its full of errors.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have also put $(Inherited) in the project and project target.

Tried pod install again. It didn't work. Then tried pod update. But no result.

How do I solve these errors ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally removed all the errors by just deleting the derived data.
After that I cleaned and rebuild the project and it ran without any errors errors.

At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not because of pushing of code. It may happen if you pulled code. In my case while using SVProgressHud  same issue occurred. Then I did like below.

1) I removed all pods from pod file then added again and installed.

2) Make sure you opened xcworkspace xcode project file.

3) Delete derived data.

4) But still I was facing the same then I did force quit Xcode, cleaned Xcode  finally worked.